# React-Redux: send a fetched API data from a component to a dynamic route component using a button inside a table

Tags: react-redux, react-router, dynamic-routing

I'm building an app with react-redux and have 3 main problems. In a volenteer component, I get data of volenteers from the store and then show it in a table component by passing it the data and columns (imported as constants).

**The Volenteer component :**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { requestVolunteerData } from '../actions';
import { volenteerColumns as columns } from '../utils/constants';
import '../container/App.css';
import Table from '../components/Table/Table';
import Loading from '../components/Loading/Loading';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        entities: state.requestEntitiesReducer.entities,
        isPending: state.requestEntitiesReducer.isPending,
        error: state.requestEntitiesReducer.error
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onRequestEntities: () => dispatch(requestVolunteerData())
    }
}

class Volenteer extends Component{
    
    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.onRequestEntities();
    }   
      
    render () {
        const { entities, isPending} = this.props;
        return isPending ?
            <Loading />
             :
            (
                <div className='tc'>
                    <h1 className='f1'>רשימת מתנדבים</h1>
                    <Table data={ entities } columns={ columns }/>  
                </div>
            );  
    }   
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Volenteer);
```

**The constants file - contain the volenteerColumns :**

```
 import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
    // Types
    export const REQUEST_ENTITIES_PENDING = 'REQUEST_ENTITIES_PENDING';
    export const REQUEST_ENTITIES_SUCCES = 'REQUEST_ENTITIES_SUCCES';
    export const REQUEST_ENTITIES_FAILED = 'REQUEST_ENTITIES_FAILED';
    
// Columns

export const volenteerColumns = [{
    dataField: 'name',
    text: 'שם פרטי'
  }, {
    dataField: 'name',
    text: 'שם משפחה'
  }, {
    dataField: 'phone',
    text: 'עיר'
  },{
    dataField: 'yeshuv',
    text: 'כתובת'
  },{
    dataField: 'phone',
    text: 'מספר טלפון'
  },{
    dataField: 'area',
    text: 'איזור פעילות מועדף'
  },{
    dataField: 'occupation',
    text: 'תחום עיסוק'
  }, {
    dataField: 'alertDonationInArea',
    text: 'התראה על תרומה באיזור'
  }, {
    dataField: 'alertdonationNearBy',
    text: 'התראה על תרומה קרובה'
  }, {
    dataField: 'status',
    text: 'סטטוס'
  }, {
    dataField: 'bDate',
    text: 'תאריך יום הולדת'
  }, {
    dataField: "_id",
    text: "פעולות",
    formatter: (rowContent, row) => {
      return (    
        <Link to={`/volenteerRoute/${_id}`}>
          <button className='btn btn-outline-primary btn lg'>view</button>
        </Link>
      )
    }
}];
```

**and its look like this:**

[image]

all I want is that when I click on the view button, it will go to a new route: `<Route path='/volenteerRoute/:id' component={VolenteerDetails} />`

and will show te data of this specific volenteer.
my problems are:

1. For now I want to import the volenteer columns from external file if it possible (for readability reasons and short code) which is not realy constants... because the button should point to a dynamic route,
   so how do I change my route by clicking the view button?
   I know I don't write it correctly (how to use the formatter)- what is the right way to pass te volenteer ID by that button that found in an external file?
2. What is the correct way for passing the state of the volenteer to the `<Route path='/volenteerRoute/:id' component={VolenteerDetails} />`, is it by a Link like this:

   ```
    <Link to ={{pathname: "/volenteerRoute/:id",
     state: { volenteerDetails:  
     this.state.volenteerDetails}}} >
   ```

or by an action of redux (preferred) by another fetch API call? if so, how do I fetch this data? those are my action:

```
//volunteer
export const requestVolunteerData = () => getData('http://localhost:8000/api/volunteer');
export const requestOneVolunteerData = () =>  getData('http://localhost:8000/api/volunteer/:id');
```

that call the getData function:

```
import {
    REQUEST_ENTITIES_PENDING,
    REQUEST_ENTITIES_SUCCES,
    REQUEST_ENTITIES_FAILED
} from './constants';
 
export const getData = (url) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch ( {type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_PENDING} );
    fetch(url)
        .then ( response => response.json() )
        .then( resp => dispatch({type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_SUCCES, payload: resp.data }) )
        .catch(error => dispatch({type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_FAILED, payload: error}) ) 
}
```

but of course the second action does not work because I dont know how to pass the ID  from the view button to that action

3. How does the VolenteerDetails (component that should show a specific volenteer details) get the data? is it by props?

   ```
       const VolenteerDetails = ({ props}) => {
            console.log(props);
            return (
              <div>
                <h2>volenteer details </h2>
              </div>
          )
       }
   ```

sorry for the length of this question and thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this Inside `route.js`:

```
<Route exact path='/volenteerRoute' component={Volenteer} />
<Route path='/volenteerRoute/:id' component={VolenteerDetails} />
```

Table view button:

```
<Link to={{pathname: `/volenteerRoute/${item.id}`}}>View</Link>
```

You can get the id of clicked view using `react-router` `useParams()`.

`VolenteerDetails.js`:

```
const VolenteerDetails = ({ props }) => {
     let { id } = useParams();
     console.log(id);
     // with id you can fetch API or call action even read data from store
     ...
}
```

For making action for `VolenteerDetails`:

```
export const requestOneVolunteerData = (id) =>  getData(`http://localhost:8000/api/volunteer/${id}`);
```

**Bonus:** For the best experience using redux and routing I prefer using [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router)

Comment: Thanks!! I will try to implement this soon

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! it was very helpful !! except from the Table view button, it should be:

```
{
    dataField: "_id",
    text: "פעולות",
    formatter: (cell) => {
      return (    
        <Link to={`/volenteerRoute/${cell}`}>
          <button className='btn btn-outline-primary btn lg'>view</button>
        </Link>
      )
    }
}
```

because the cell of the dataField: "_id" is the one that holds the id of the volenteer here is a helpful link:
https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/advance.html

but I could not make it without your answer, so thanks again!!

I will explore connected-react-router as you recommended

Comment: Good luck bro, happy to help you :)